# Don't include an object in map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Using LoDash to map over an object:

```
_.map(items, (item) = > {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        // don't include this in final object
    }
    return _.assign({
        foo: "bar"
    }, item);
});
```

Wondering what my best tactic is for not including an object in the returned, mapped, object if the current object is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `reduce` which works perfectly for your case:

```
var items = [{a: 1}, ["asd"], {b: 2}];

var result = _.reduce(items, (res, item) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
        _.assign(res, item);
    }
  return res;
}, {foo: "bar"});
```

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/licifuyozi/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: This is very nice, I like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Another (and IMO a cleaner) solution is to use chaining:

```
results = _(items).reject(_.isArray).map(function(item) {
    ....
}).value()
```

Comment: That is cleaner, but I don't think it solves the problem. Doesn't that just not do the mapping if item is an array?  The person wants a property to exist or not exist on the returned item.

Comment: This is actually what I went for before, so this is *a* right answer, just technically not the answer I was after. @Kiril seemed to nail it.

Answer (score 0):

This... just assign an empty object if item is an array, otherwise assign item:

```
_.map(items, (item) = > {
    return _.assign({
        foo: "bar"
    }, Array.isArray(item)?{}:item);
});
```

Here's a little fiddle without the new anonymous function syntax: https://jsfiddle.net/xurm6vrr/1/

Comment: true, but isn't the item that is the array going to remain in the mapped object?

Comment: @Robert I think this just avoids setting the `foo` property, the item is not removed in the output of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a `map` function to always output the same keys as the input. The values maybe modified, but the keys remain the same.

There are other functions you can use to change the set of items like `filter` or some kind of `aggregate` or `reduce`.